# Is there a difference between "Speciality" and "Specialty"?

Tags: differences, american-english, synonyms, british-english

My work colleagues and I have been having a discussion about doctors (we work in healthcare), and we're split down the middle as to whether a specialist doctor would have a speciality, or a specialty (no "i"). Is there a specific use for each word, or can they be interchanged?

Comment: I was faced with the same dilemma when putting together my CV. I then noticed that the online database of translators housed on the website of The Chartered Institute of Linguists (of which I am a member) used another word altogether: 'specialisms' - and I eventually decided to go with that.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There seems to be divergence on that point: See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Medical_specialties). [Others](http://www.english-test.net/forum/ftopic40961.html#160716) seem to think so as well.

I suspect that *specialty* is American English and *speciality* is British English.

Comment: [This resource](http://grammarist.com/usage/speciality-specialty/) has some nice examples of BrE vs AmE usage in the press.

Answer (score 14):

*Specialty* is the word used in American English (the OED reports it's chiefly Northern American), while *speciality* is used in British English.

In medicine (as for what reported by the OED) both *specialty* and *speciality* are used.

Comment: I can confirm that in UK hospitals, consultants refer to their Specialty rather than Speciality - I know this because I "helpfully" spellchecked the user interface for an NHS computer application, and then later had to revert it when they all complained!

Answer (score 6):

It's standard US medical editing practice to change instances of "specialities" to "specialties." Note the certifying agency: [American Board of Medical Specialties](http://www.abms.org/).

Answer (score 3):

There's a good explanation of the difference [here](https://grammarist.com/usage/speciality-specialty/).

In addition to the regional differences among English-speaking nations, it points out that 'specialty' is more commonly used as an adjective; 'speciality' as a noun.

As a native speaker of British English, this is the distinction I make.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, both of them mean the same thing. The usage is the only difference. Like *prioritise* and *prioritize*.