# What is called a special academic subject that is pursued by postgraduates after bachelor degree?

Tags: single-word-requests

In many countries, academics pursue a special field, typically a branch of their bachelor subject, as MS students. For example someone who has studied computer engineering in bachelor degree, might choose to study one of its branches like computer hardware architecture, computer software, IT, artificial intelligence, etc. for MS degree. What do you call this special field of study sought usually in post-graduate stage? Is is subject, field, discipline, specialty, or something else? Persians call it [Gerayesh (=گرایش)](http://www.vajehyab.com/dictionary/%DA%AF%D8%B1%D8%A7%DB%8C%D8%B4), literally meaning attraction, interest. But I am not knowledgeable of any English equivalent for this usage.

Comment: [Specialty or speciality](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/25753/is-there-a-difference-between-speciality-and-specialty) are possibilities

Answer (score 2):

I believe the phrase you're looking for is specialization.  The verb is specialize.

Comment: You could also use the word focus.

Answer (score 2):

I would call this a *specialization* or *specialty*.