# Why "sovereignty" instead of "sovereignity"?

Tags: orthography

The common form of forming noun from some adjectives is to add the suffix "-ity" as in "verbose" -> "verbosity", "national" -> "nationality".

But why does "sovereign" becomes "sovereignty" instead of "sovereignity"? Is there some sort of etymological reason for this? And is this word the only one with this behavior?

Comment: I wish *[Is there a difference between “Speciality” and “Specialty”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/25753/)* provided more insight than it does.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

"Sovereignty" isn't the only noun ending in "-ty" instead of "-ity". We also have

- certainty
- royalty, loyalty, cruelty, fealty, frailty, penalty, admiralty
- liberty, puberty, property, poverty
- honesty, majesty

Some of these are from Latin words that didn't have "i" in this context: e.g. *liberty* = L. *libertas,* *majesty* = L. *majestas* (*maiestas*), *puberty* = L. *pubertas.*

Others are from French, where the suffix *-té* is fairly often not preceded by "i" (Latin vowels are often weakened or lost in French): e.g. *cruelty,* according to the Oxford English Dictionary (OED) from

> Old French *crualté* (later *cruauté*), according to Hatzfeld < popular Latin type **crūdālitāt-em,* for *crūdēlitāt-em* (see crudelity n.)

Some of these are related to words ending in *-ity*: although "crudelity" is extremely uncommon, there are words like "regality" (from the same etymological source as *royalty*) and "fragility" (from the same etymological source as *frailty*). *Property* is related to *propriety*: the suffix has the form *-ety* here because of the preceding *i*.

You can see some more information about the Latin suffix *-itas/-etas/-tas* and the distribution of its variants on the following page: "[§46. The Latin suffix -ITAS (> E -ity); variant -ETAS (> E -ety)](https://pressbooks.bccampus.ca/greeklatinroots/chapter/%C2%A746-the-latin-suffix-itas-e-ity-variant-etas-e-ety/)" (Smith, Peter. (2016). Greek and Latin Roots: for Science and the Social Sciences, Part I – Latin).

### The etymology of *sovereign*

As mentioned in user159691's answer, *sovereignty* comes from French. The OED says

> < Anglo-Norman *sovereyneté, soverentee,* = Old French *souveraineté* (modern French *souvraineté*)

The word *sovereign* is supposed to be from

> popular Latin **superānus* (OED)

As you can see, there isn't a "gn" in the Latin source (it is thought to come from *super* + the Latin suffix *-ānus;* compare *christian* and *christianity* from Latin *chrīstiānus, chrīstiānitās*).

The digraph "gn" was probably introduced into the English spelling of "sovereign" by mere analogy with other words spelled with word-final "gn" (according to [Etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/word/sovereign), proabably association with the word "reign" in particular).

The OED does list a few examples of "sovereignity" with "-ity", but says this word is obsolete. The earliest example it lists, from "c1560", uses the spelling "souerenitie" without "gn". The OED also mentions the related word *[sovranità](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/sovranita/)* in Italian.

"Gn" does show up before "ity" in words where "gn" comes from Latin, like *benignity* and *malignity* (Italian *[benignità](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/benignita/)* and *[malignità](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/malignita/)*). In English, the letter "g" corresponds to a consonant [g] that is pronounced in these nouns, although there is no [g] in the pronunciation of the adjectives *benign* and *malign.*

Comment: A good answer, although this could be improved as to which category does "sovereignty" belong, and thus explaining the origin of its suffix. =)

Comment: "Superānus" is a great word. Do I correctly assume that speakers of popular Latin did not feel warmly toward their sovereign? ;-)

Comment: @ruakh: lol. I added a sentence about the apparent etymology of "superānus"

Answer (score 3):

It is could in terms of French origin whose suffix was “-te”:

***[-ty](https://www.etymonline.com/word/-ty)***:

> suffix used in forming abstract nouns from adjectives (such as safety, surety), Middle English -tie, -te, ***from Old French -te (Modern French -té),***  from Latin -tatem (nominative -tas, genitive -tatis), cognate with Greek -tes, Sanskrit -tati-.

***[sovereignty](https://www.etymonline.com/word/sovereignty) (n.):***

> mid-14c., "pre-eminence," ***from Anglo-French sovereynete, Old French souverainete***, from soverain (see sovereign (adj.)). Meaning "authority, rule, supremacy of power or rank" is recorded from late 14c.; sense of "existence as an independent state" is from 1715.

(Etymonline)

Answer (score 1):

Sovereign and sovereignty are existing nouns representing something. The -ty suffix most likely derives from the meaning ["quality or state of something"](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/-ty), or the state of being sovereign.

-ity is a suffix to be added to adjectives in the process of converting them into an abstract noun.

Examples: Technicality, possibility, probability, responsibility.

Source: [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/-ity)

Comment: Perhaps this can be augmented with also the definition of the suffix -ty and how both of them distinguish "sovereignty" and "sovereignity", if indeed as you say both forms exist in English? I think at least you need to also cite http://www.dictionary.com/browse/-ty and expand your answer based on that.

Comment: Sovereignity is not a word, as "-ity" is applied to adjectives. Sovereign is a noun, so it wouldn't apply

Comment: "sovereign" is both a noun and an adjective.

Comment: You are correct, my mistake.